# Create dynamic ids for wordpress gallerie shortcode from custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, image-gallery, custom-fields, shortcode

this is my first post, always nice to read other questions. I'm looking for a solution to insert ids into a Wordpress Gallery Shortcode from Custom Fields i created with the ACF-Plugins.

The shortcode is looking like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery type="carousel" ids="47,48,49,etc..."]'); ?>
```

I whould like to replace the specific ID's (numbers) with the value which is provided by the Custom Field. For example:

```
<?php echo get_field('galleryimage_1'); ?>
<?php echo get_field('galleryimage_2'); ?>
```

This would give me the correct first and second ID, I just don't have a clue how to include it into the shortcode.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using just the standard ACF custom fields (and not the Gallery nor Repeater ACF add-ons), I'd suggest:

```
<?php $limit = 10; //number of your galleryimage_n fields
$imgArr = array();
for($ctr = 1; $ctr <= $limit; $ctr++){
    $value = get_field('galleryimage_' . $ctr);
    if($value){
        $imgArr[] = $value;
    }
}
$imgIds = implode(",", $imgArr);
echo do_shortcode('[gallery type="carousel" ids="'. $imgIds .'"]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks good, way better then my solution:

```
echo do_shortcode('[gallery type="carousel" ids="' . get_field('galleriebild_1') . ', "]');
```